# known for vs known to

Tags: word-usage

Has these two sentences got any difference between them:

> 1.*He has been **known to** spend all morning in the bathroom.*
> 2.*He has been **known for** spending all morning in the bathroom.*

Is there any difference between **'known to'** and **'known for'** in these sentences?

Answer (score 3):

1. It means that it has occasionally happened.
2. If you are *known for* doing something, your habit of doing it is well known.

Comment: Not only is your habit of doing something well known - the strong implication there is that if it weren't for the fact that people know you do that thing, *they wouldn't even know you existed at all* (i.e. - they only know who you are because they know you do that thing).